# Searching a custom object

Tags: vb.net, object, search

As a follow-up to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71368111/how-do-i-construct-an-add-routine-for-a-custom-object-list), and continuing with the sample code in [the answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71368111/how-do-i-construct-an-add-routine-for-a-custom-object-list#answer-71368263), how can I e.g. find out if a `ParameterSet` exists in my `ParameterSetCollection` with a `Y` parameter of `"foobar"`?  I can write code to iterate over the `ParameterSet`, but it seems there should be a better way.

Comment: [IEquatable<T> Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1), [IComparable<T> Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1)

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Dim parameterSets As New ParameterSetCollection

'...

If parameterSetCollection.Any(Function(ps) ps.Y = "foobar") Then
    'At least one item in the collection has a Y value of "foobar".
End If
```

`Any` is a LINQ method and LINQ excels at compressing loops. That code is functionally equivalent to this:

```vb
Dim parameterSets As New ParameterSetCollection

'...

Dim match = False

For Each ps In parameterSetCollection
    If ps.Y = "foobar" Then
        match = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next

If match Then
    'At least one item in the collection has a Y value of "foobar".
End If
```